# Flot graph not working, but not erroring

Tags: jquery, flot

So I have Flot running, the graph axis etc draws, however the points do not get plotted.

For example this is the code that gets run (you can use the JS Inspector on Chrome and run the code on http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-types/index.html)

**JS:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $.plot('#placeholder',[ [0,0],[1, 25],[5, 2],[7, 165],[8, 520],[9, 962],[10, 123] ]); 
});
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
```

The code runs but doesn't error - so I'm not sure what is going wrong here?

I've ran the same code on the Flot site and causes the same issue.

**P.S I'm trying to get a JSFiddle together for this**

Comment: fiddle for this - http://jsfiddle.net/2jaAR/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to wrap your data in an additional array, like this:

```
$.plot('#placeholder', [[[0, 0], ...]]);
```

Flot expects an array of series, where each series is an array of points.  Without an outer array Flot therefore interprets each of your points as its own series whose data is invalid.  See the [Data Format](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format) section of the docs for more info.

Comment: Perfect thank you, didn't realise, I'd added the second set of brackets but didn't realise a third was needed.